# netbiosd tries to connect to RFC1918 network addresses

Tags: network

After installing Little Snitch firewall, I have got regular notifications that netbiosd is trying to make outbound connections to addresses in 10.88.0.0/16 networks. All my IP networks are in `192.168.0.0/16` space.

So, the question is, does anyone know why netbiosd is trying to connect to a non-routable RFC1918 network which does not exist? Where does it get this IP address?